# How to handle errors in Mercurial extension

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-extension

What is the recommended approach to handling errors in a Mercurial extension? We could not find any docs for this aspect online.

The following example will print `Hello world` and set `errorlevel` to `1` in a Windows shell.

```
@command('print-parents', [('','', None, '')], '')
def printparents(ui, repo, node, **opts):
  print "Hello world"
  return True
```

Why is `errorlevel` set to `1`? We expected it to be `0`. How does Python or Mercurial handle `True` and `False` in this context? Changing to return `False` produces `errorlevel` `0`.

We have seen some examples of `raise error.Abort(..)` but this output a very verbose callstack which is not neccessary. A simple text message and correct `errorlevel` is what is needed.

Using Windows 7 and Mercurial 3.4.1

Comment: Why does your command return `True` at all? The return value of a `@command` is interpreted as the exit code and in Python, `True == 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `@command` function, use `ui.warn()` to display an error message, then return an *integer* value to set the exit code:

```
if something_is_wrong:
    ui.warn(_('Something is wrong, please correct this'))
    return 1
```

However, using `raise mercurial.error.Abort()` is fine too and doesn't result in a traceback unless you have `ui.traceback` set to `True` (it defaults to `False`). Raising `Abort()` normally results in a `ui.warn('abort: ' + msg_from_exception)` and `return -1` combo (which results in a 255 exit code):

```
$ cat demo.py
from mercurial import cmdutil, error

cmdtable = {}
command = cmdutil.command(cmdtable)

@command('demo1', [], '')
def demo1(ui, repo, *args, **opts):
    ui.warn('Error message written directly to ui.warn')
    return 1

@command('demo2', [], '')
def demo2(ui, repo, *args, **opts):
    raise error.Abort('Error message raised with Abort')

$ hg --config extensions.demo=`pwd`/demo.py demo1
Error message written directly to ui.warn
$ echo $?
1
$ hg --config extensions.demo=`pwd`/demo.py demo2
abort: Error message raised with Abort
$?
255
$ hg --config extensions.demo=`pwd`/demo.py --config ui.traceback=true demo2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 204, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 880, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 210, in closure
    return func(*(args + a), **kw)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fastmanifest/cachemanager.py", line 318, in runcommandtrigger
    result = orig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 210, in closure
    return func(*(args + a), **kw)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fastmanifest/__init__.py", line 174, in _logonexit
    r = orig(ui, repo, cmd, fullargs, *args)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 210, in closure
    return func(*(args + a), **kw)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgext/journal.py", line 79, in runcommand
    return orig(lui, repo, cmd, fullargs, *args)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 637, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 210, in closure
    return func(*(args + a), **kw)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgext/pager.py", line 160, in pagecmd
    return orig(ui, options, cmd, cmdfunc)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 210, in closure
    return func(*(args + a), **kw)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgext/color.py", line 503, in colorcmd
    return orig(ui_, opts, cmd, cmdfunc)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1010, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 971, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 877, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/opt/facebook/hg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 1036, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/demo/demo.py", line 13, in demo2
    raise error.Abort('Error message raised with Abort')
Abort: Error message raised with Abort
abort: Error message raised with Abort
```

Note that I had to explicitly enable the traceback!

In Python, the `bool` type is a subclass of `int`, and `True` has a value of `1` and `False` has an integer value of `0`. Because Mercurial expects `@command` functions to return an integer to set an exit code (or `None` for exit code 0), you set the exit code to `1` by returning `True`.

I generally look over the `mercurial.commands` module and the various `hgext` extensions to learn how others have solved specific problems. The `hg grep` command, for example, contains this example of handling an error:

```
try:
    regexp = util.re.compile(pattern, reflags)
except re.error as inst:
    ui.warn(_("grep: invalid match pattern: %s\n") % inst)
    return 1
```

while the `hg addremove` code raises `error.Abort()`:

```
try:
    sim = float(opts.get('similarity') or 100)
except ValueError:
    raise error.Abort(_('similarity must be a number'))
```

I'd use `error.Abort()` for command errors, and `ui.warn()` plus returning an integer only if you specifically need an exit code other than 255.